# Not able to change git branch

Tags: git

I am new to git. I changed my current branch via terminal by using

```
git checkout -b branch1
```

After that I created another branch

```
git checkout -b branch2
```

Now I am not able to change the branch back to branch1. I dont know whats wrong.I tried the following code

```
git checkout -b branch1
```

I am using smartgit to access git files.

Comment: _"I am not able to"_ - why not? What happens? Did you read the message and research it?

Comment: If you are creating a new branch that does not exist `git checkout -b branch1`, if it already exists `git checkout branch1`. The `-b` indicates the creation of a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are creating the branch which is already existing. To switch to the existing branch, use this

```
git checkout branch1
```

Comment: Anyway you formatted most of the description as code. Don't do that.

Comment: I will try my best next time onwards.

Answer (score 0):

[`git checkout -b branch1`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutem-b-Bltnewbranchgtltstartpointgt) is a shortcut for:

```
git branch branch1
git checkout branch1
```

[`git branch branch1`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) creates a new branch named `branch1` starting from the current commit. It fails if the branch `branch1` already exists and this is why your second use of `git checkout -b branch1` fails.

[`git checkout branch1`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) is the command to checkout `branch1` if it already exists. You can use `git checkout -b branch1` only once, when `branch1` does not exist.

Read more about [`git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) and [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout).

Answer (score 0):

I get it. Its because of the  extra -b in front of the command.